# Adding text between 2 html tags

Tags: python, html, text-mining

I am a 2 years student and I am working on text mining.

For general let me tell you about the code it first accept pdf type text and convert that in to **doc.txt** file, then I process that data for couple of hundred lines then after i store all sentences in that text to the list called **all_text** (for th future  use) and also I select some texts and store them in to a list called **summary**.

Finally the problem is on this part:

Summary list look like this

```
summary=['Artificial Intelligence (AI) is a science and a set of computational technologies that are inspired by—but typically operate quite differently from—the ways people use their nervous systems and bodies to sense, learn, reason, and take action.','In reality, AI is already changing our daily lives, almost entirely in ways that improve human health, safety,and productivity.','AI is also changing how people interact with technology.']
```

What I want is read from doc.txt sentence by sentence and if that sentence is in the summary list modify that sentence by put it in to BOLD tag " **the sentence**" for all in the summary list here is small code i tried for that specific part it not help full but here it is

```
while i < len(lis):
    if lis[i] in txt:
        txt = txt.replace(lis[i], "<b>" + lis[i] + "</b>")

        print(lis[i])

   i += 1
```

This code did not work as I expected, I mean it works for some short sentences, but it doesn't work for the sentences like those I don't have any idea why it's not working help me please?

Comment: Give a concrete example please.

Comment: Ok. For example you have a text file which contains alot of sentences and you have some sentences out of that text file then search those sentences that you have  from that text file then if you find that specific sentences in the text file add  the sentences in bold tage

Comment: I mean where exactly your code fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose you might use list comprehension, example:

```
summary = ['sentenceE','sentenceA']
text = ['sentenceA','sentenceB','sentenceC','sentenceD','sentenceE']
output = ['<b>'+i+'</b>' if (i in summary) else i for i in text]
print(output) #prints ['<b>sentenceA</b>', 'sentenceB', 'sentenceC', 'sentenceD', '<b>sentenceE</b>']
```

Note that `summary` and `text` should be `list`s of `str`s.